# Why isn't there any complement for 'do'?

Tags: complements

> Malfoy now turned to Hagrid. 
>       "I'm not going in that forest, he said, and Harry was pleased to hear the note of panic in his voice. 
>       "Yeh are if yeh want ter stay at Hogwarts," said Hagrid fiercely. "Yeh've done wrong an' now yeh’ve got ter pay fer it." 
>       "But this is servant stuff, it's not **for students to do**. I thought we'd be copying lines or something, if my father knew I was
>   doing this, he'd ––“
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

There is a ‘for’ complementizer in the case. But when considering ‘do’ is a transitive verb, there needs to be ‘what’ or ‘that’. What grammatical explanations are there?

Comment: There's already an "it", just moved to the beginning. "It's not for students to do" is just a reordered version of "Students are not to do it".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But then where does the *for* come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *for .. to* construction here is misleading. The phrase is a marriage of two different constructions:

*For* here is not a complementizer, but an ordinary preposition:

> It is [a job] **for** students.

And the infinitive is attributive:

> They have [a job] **to do**.

That construction was discussed at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2726/32). In the form I have just shown it is the direct ancestor of the modern semi-modal *have to*: "They **have to do** this job.

When you put these together you get "a job **for students to do**", which looks like a defective nominal *for .. to* clause but is actually an adjectival prepositional phrase -- serving here as a predicative complement.